# ngrx dealing with nested array in object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, redux, ngrx

I am learning the redux pattern and using ngrx with angular 2. I am creating a sample blog site which has following shape.

```js
export interface BlogContent {
  id: string;
  header: string;
  tags: string[];
  title: string;
  actualContent: ActualContent[];
}
```

and my reducer and actions are as following:

```js
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
export interface ActualContent {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  data: string;
}

export interface BlogContent {
  id: string;
  header: string;
  tags: string[];
  title: string;
  actualContent: ActualContent[];
}

export const initialState: BlogContent = {
  id: '',
  header: '',
  tags: [],
  title: '',
  actualContent: [],
};

export const ADD_OPERATION = 'ADD_OPERATION';
export const REMOVE_OPERATION = 'REMOVE_OPERATION';
export const RESET_OPERATION = 'RESET_OPERATION';
export const ADD_IMAGE_ID = 'ADD_IMAGE_ID';
export const ADD_FULL_BLOG = 'ADD_FULL_BLOG';
export const ADD_BLOG_CONTENT_OPERATION = 'ADD_BLOG_CONTENT_OPERATION';
export const ADD_BLOG_TAG_OPERATION = 'ADD_BLOG_TAG_OPERATION';

export const blogContent: ActionReducer<BlogContent> = (state: BlogContent= initialState, action: Action ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case  ADD_OPERATION :
        return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload );
      case  ADD_BLOG_CONTENT_OPERATION :
        return Object.assign({}, state, { actualContent: [...state.actualContent, action.payload]});
        case  ADD_BLOG_TAG_OPERATION :
        return Object.assign({}, state, { tags: [...state.tags, action.payload]});
      case REMOVE_OPERATION :
        return Object.assign({}, state, { actualContent: state.actualContent.filter((blog) => blog.id !== action.payload.id) });
      case ADD_IMAGE_ID : {
        let index = _.findIndex(state.actualContent, {id: action.payload.id});
        console.log(index);
        if ( index >= 0 ) {
          return  Object.assign({}, state, {
            actualContent :  [
              ...state.actualContent.slice(0, index),
              action.payload,
              ...state.actualContent.slice(index + 1)
            ]
          });
        }
        return state;
      }
      default :
        return state;
    }
};
```

and this is working fine but i am not sure if its the right approach or should i somehow separate the ActualContent into its own reducer and actions and then merge them. 
Sorry if this post does not belong here and you can guide me where should put this post and i will remove it from here. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have done some research but couldnt find any article that has complex nested objects so that i can refer. Please add any useful blog links of ngrx or related topic which can help me out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of having a nested structure

```
export interface BlogContent {
  id: string;
  header: string;
  tags: string[];
  title: string;
  actualContent: ActualContent[]; <------ NESTED
}
```

You should have a normalized state.

For example here you should have something like :

```
// this should be into your store
export interface BlogContents {
  byId: { [key: string]: BlogContent };
  allIds: string[];
}

// this is made to type the objects you'll find in the byId
export interface BlogContent {
  id: string;
  // ...
  actualContentIds: string[];
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------

// this should be into your store
export interface ActualContents {
  byId: { [key: string]: ActualContent };
  allIds: string[];
}

export interface ActualContent {
  id: string;
  // ...
}
```

So if you try to populate your store it'd look like that :

```
const blogContentsState: BlogContents = {
  byId: {
    blogContentId0: {
      id: 'idBlogContent0',
      // ...
      actualContentIds: ['actualContentId0', 'actualContentId1', 'actualContentId2']
    }
  },
  allIds: ['blogContentId0']
};

const actualContentState: ActualContents = {
  byId: {
    actualContentId0: {
      id: 'actualContentId0',
      // ...
    },
    actualContentId1: {
      id: 'actualContentId1',
      // ...
    },
    actualContentId2: {
      id: 'actualContentId2',
      // ...
    }
  },
  allIds: ['actualContentId0', 'actualContentId1', 'actualContentId2']
};
```

In your logic or view (for example with Angular), you need your nested structure so you can iterate over your array and thus, you don't want to iterate on a string array of IDs. Instead you'd like `actualContent: ActualContent[];`.

For that, you create a `selector`. Every time your store change, your selector will kicks in and generate a new "view" of your raw data.

```
// assuming that you can blogContentsState and actualContentsState from your store
const getBlogContents = (blogContentsState, actualContentsState) =>
  blogContentsState
    .allIds
    .map(blogContentId => ({
      ...blogContentsState.byId[blogContentId],

      actualContent: blogContentsState
        .byId[blogContentId]
        .actualContentIds
        .map(actualContentId => actualContentsState.byId[actualContentId])
    }));
```

I know it can be a lot to process at the beginning and I invite you to read the [official doc about selectors and normalized state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/)

As you're learning ngrx, you might want to take a look into a small project I've made called Pizza-Sync. [Code source is on Github](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync). It's a project were I've done something like that to demo :). (You should also  definitely install the [ReduxDevTools app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) to see how is the store).

I made a small video focus only on Redux with Pizza-Sync if you're interested : https://youtu.be/I28m9lwp15Y

Comment: how do you normally normalize data ?  backend  or use normalizr or store data in the same format ?

Comment: That's a good question :) ! At work, we do have an API but it makes no sense for our users to use it. So we decided that the backend should send the normalized data directly. If you want to work with a public (classic) REST API or if you intend to open your API, I'd recommend you to use normalizr.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It clears up lots of things.

Comment: Glad to hear it ! :)

Comment: @Maxime FYI there is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45328915/6680611) (from a user without sufficient rep to comment) that relates to this answer.

Comment: Thanks @cartant I'll try to find some time in the next few days to help :)

Comment: I don't like sacrificing the richness of the model to suit a framework. Not commenting on this specific answer.  the general notion out there in ngrx world is what is recommended but the readers should know what they are getting into.

Comment: I think that you're mixing up the richness of the model and the shape of the model. This isn't recommended for ngrx (only), it's just a brilliant concept to manage your state. If you have nested entities, let say that some users have some dogs. You create a list to display all the users. Easy right?  Well now you also display for each users their dogs. Easy. NOW, you want to display a given dog when you click on it. And have the possibility to edit that dog. So you do that onto another page of your SPA, let say /dog/1 but how do you retrieve that dog from your model (just knowing it's ID)?

Comment: You go first through all the users and through all their dogs? That is absolutely not optimized nor convenient. Imagine with a 10 levels nested structure! And this is not the only problem. For example, if amongst your users you have a family. So they all have the same dogs but duplicated for each person. When you click on a person and edit one of the dogs of that family, you'll have to go once again through all the users to update the duplicated dog.

Comment: Whereas if you have a normalized structure you can just access dogs[dogId] to read or edit it, and thanks to the selector, the dog will be updated for the whole family (as it's the same one for them, one shared entity). I hope I helped you to understand why it's important to normalize your structure, if you have any other argument against, let me know.