# What is this ngrx selector doing?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm trying to better understand the answer by Maxime to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667853/ngrx-dealing-with-nested-array-in-object). My rep is not high enough to comment on the answer there, so I'll ask a new question here.

The part about setting up a normalized state makes sense. Then he goes on to talk about how you would create a selector, this part of his answer is quoted below, and showing his code block.

> In your logic or view (for example with Angular), you need your nested structure so you can iterate over your array and thus, you don't want to iterate on a string array of IDs. Instead you'd like actualContent: ActualContent[];.
>
> For that, you create a selector. Every time your store change, your selector will kicks in and generate a new "view" of your raw data.

```
// assuming that you can blogContentsState and actualContentsState from your store
const getBlogContents = (blogContentsState, actualContentsState) =>
  blogContentsState
    .allIds
    .map(blogContentId => ({
      ...blogContentsState.byId[blogContentId],

      actualContent: blogContentsState
        .byId[blogContentId]
        .actualContentIds
        .map(actualContentId => actualContentsState.byId[actualContentId])
   }));
```

My question is, whether or not there is still a type definition of `BlogContent` with an `actualContent` array nested?

```
export interface BlogContent {
  id: string;
  header: string;
  tags: string[];
  title: string;
  actualContent: ActualContent[]; <------ NESTED
}
```

I don't quite understand what the selector `getBlogContents` is doing and how this would be used in a component that wants to display blogContents with a nested list of actualContents, can this be explained in a little more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@cartant pinged me on my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667853/ngrx-dealing-with-nested-array-in-object) so here I am (thx @cartant!).

I do think a lot about my interfaces within an app. I think it's important to have well defined interfaces or we'll end up with a mess :).

I've tried to create a basic pattern for it, as often, we end up with the same idea:

**One resource:**
 - resource without details
 - resource with details
 - composed resource, where foreign keys with only IDs are replaced by corresponding resources
 - composed resource with also UI variables (to show a state, for example fetching, downloading, etc)

**A "table", which contains multiple of those resources:**
 - contains normalized data, with for example `byId` and `allIds`
 - contains some UI variables, this time not for every items, but the table (state for adding a resource would go there as the resource is not in the list yet for example)

I've made such a detailed example within `angular-ngrx-starter`, [here for the interfaces](https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter/blob/8f9c2bdd3f36e1c5d726795e0d2bfe1a2679b34f/src/app/shared/states/pizzas/pizzas.interfaces.ts).

By the way, you might be interested by the [whole folder](https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter/tree/8f9c2bdd3f36e1c5d726795e0d2bfe1a2679b34f/src/app/shared/states/pizzas), which is a complete example is this starter (actions, reducer, effects, interfaces ,selectors, service and mock for the service).

Hope it helps you understand but keep in mind that this is not perfect! It's just one way, my way of seeing things.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, whether or not there is still a type definition of
>   BlogContent with an actualContent array nested?

BlogContent only contains an array of ids for actualContent.

> I don't quite understand what the selector getBlogContents is doing
>   and how this would be used in a component that wants to display
>   blogContents with a nested list of actualContents, can this be
>   explained in a little more detail?

Maxime references his own project where he does a similar pattern.

Here's his selector: https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/master/frontend/src/app/shared/states/orders/orders.selector.ts

Then he uses it here: https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/b127ef963640d67f7560fad69f6f8364355ac697/frontend/src/app/features/order-summary-dialog/order-summary-dialog.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.orderSummary$ = this.store$.let(getOrderSummary);
}
```

Note that this is the old way to do selectors.  The ngrx example app used to use it but they've refactored to use reselect.js for all selectors.

Comment: Hey seescode I'm glad to see you've looked into pizza-sync :)! Yes I know that I do not use reselect into pizza-sync but I plan to upgrade it to ngrx v4 once it gets more stable (I've had few bugs with this major upgrade and I'm waiting for some issues to get closed on their github). Once it's fine, I'll make a refactor and I'll use createSelector provided by ngrx v4, which does the same than reselect :)

Comment: Thanks for making your project public.  I haven't tried out ngrx v4 but it is useful to know that I should wait longer before trying it out.

Comment: Yes, indeed I'm not the only one to notice incompatibilities between ngrx v4 and AOT. If you don't use AOT compilation (which would be too bad) then you might go for it. Also, if you have an app to migrate to ngrx v4, you can already start because everything seems to work fine in dev mode, without AOT.

Comment: If you liked pizza-sync, you should definitely take a look into [angular-ngrx-starter](https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter) which is a starter I've made to kickstart an ngrx project :) I've tried to explain a lot of things into the readme